# Access UIView Methods from Controller / Add UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In the ViewController I would like to:

1) Detect if the UIView has been selected
2) Insert an image at the coordinates.

How do I do this? I'm currently using:

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:theViewIWant];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.jpg"];
[myImage drawAtPoint:touchPoint];
```

But this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do what you want is to create a `UIImageView` which you insert or remove as a subview when appropriate.

However, why go to all that trouble when `UIButton` already provides this functionality? Just create a button of type [UIButtonTypeCustom](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIButtonTypeCustom) and set a background image only for the "highlighted" state.

Comment: How do I call a method in the view from the controller? I'm finding it quite hard understanding what to do - it's quite difficult coming from a Java background.

Comment: For a button, you really just need to do something like `[button setBackgroundImage:myImage forControlState:UIControlStateHighlighted]` when you initialize it. The button itself will then automatically handle touch events and highlight appropriately. If you need a method to be called when the user taps the button, you can use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW4

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. If I could bother you with just another quick question: How do I create an array that is going to be edited by the controller but the view needs access to it?

Comment: That's a complex enough question that you might want to open up a new thread. Without knowing any specifics, one answer is probably that the view *shouldn't* have access to it, but should use delegation to get the data it needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In case you want a go at that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361989/passing-array-from-controller-to-view