# Passing Array From Controller to View

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have:

1. UIView
2. UIViewController

In the UIViewController I need to be able to insert items into a fixed array of 6 integers. Then, I need to pass this array to the view in order for it to analyse the array and update the screen appropriately. How do I go about doing this? I've tried using standard C arrays but doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use C arrays as arguments to methods, nor can you pass them to something. You have two options:

1. Use an NSArray of six NSNumbers, each containing an int.
2. Use a pointer to the C array.

Which one you choose is up to you. Option 1 is more iPhone-alike. Option 2 is less memory-consuming.

Comment: Agreed. Option 1 uses more memory, however it's quick and dirty way of getting things done.

Answer (score 1):

Because objective c doesn't allow C arrays to be passed to objective c methods unless they are sent as pointers, Here is one method:

```
// MyViewController.m
#define BOX_INT(ARG_1) [NSNumber numberWithInt:ARG_1];

....

-(void) somethingHappened:(id) sender
{
    // initialize the array:
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:BOX_INT(ints[0]), BOX_INT(ints[1]), BOX_INT(ints[2]), BOX_INT(ints[3]), BOX_INT(ints[4]), BOX_INT(ints[5]), nil];
    [myView passArray:array];
}


// MyView.m
#define UNBOX_INT(ARG_1) [ARG_1 intValue];

....

-(void) passArray:(NSArray *) array
{
     int intArray[6];

     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     {
          intArray[i] = UNBOX_INT([array objectAtIndex:i]);
     }

     ...
}
```

Or, you can just pass a pointer (not recommended)

```
// MyController.m

-(void) somethingHappened:(id) sender
{
    [myView passArray:ints];
}

-(void) passArray:(int *) array
{
    // think of array as an integer array, with a length of 6.
}
```

Comment: May I ask what `#define UNBOX_INT(ARG_1) [ARG_1 intValue];` does?

Comment: it defines a macro that is equivalent to the function:
`int UNBOX_INT(NSNumber *num) {  return [num intValue];  }`

Comment: Is it possible to declare this array in the header file, then access within the .m file individual elements to update? i.e. `myArray[5] = 356;`?

Comment: Yes, but it has to be a `variable` not a property. Variables are accessed by the pointer syntax.. e.g. `myView->ints[i] = ints[i];`

Comment: I see, so for example, if I have an `int a = 5;` and i want to insert that at position 4 of NSArray, what would that be?

Comment: NSArrays cannot be modified. NSMutableArrays are what you want, and you would need: `[myView->myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:BOX_INT(a)];`

Answer (score 0):

There' has always been a discussion for how to share objects between two classes . 
So broadly speaking there are three methods:-

1. Singleton Objects
2. Global Variables
3. Appdelegate variables

However if u really want to pass an array from ViewController to View , I would recommend going with 3rd method i.e. AppDelegate Variables. And yes that's always pointed that this is **quick** but **Dirty** method.

So what you can do is declare and Array in Appdelegate.

Now to insert items into that array in ur viewcontroller

```
UrAppDelegate* delegate = (UrAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[delegate.urArrayName addObject:@"someObject"];
```

And then when  u want to use that in ur view.. just go ahead and use the same method above.